# Splitting SD file

Tags: docking

I have one sd file of 3.5 GB size.I want to split it in ~200MB fragments.I dont have much coding knowledge.Please tell me various tools and methods for the same.I have windows 7 and ubuntu 12.04 systems.

Comment: What's an SD file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
split -b200m InputFile  OutputSmallFile
```